# LINQ Insert - No Error but no insert either

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm using the following code to insert a new entry in my existing db. But the new record doesn't get inserted. What are the options to fetch a possible exception? 
What could be the reason that this doesn't work?

Thanks,
rAyt

```
using (ContactManagerSampleDataDataContext db = new ContactManagerSampleDataDataContext())
                    {
                        CustomerCompany company = new CustomerCompany();
                        company.CompanyName = "Test";
                        company.IsActive = true;
                        company.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        company.SapNumber = 1;
                        company.CompanyId = 1;

                        db.CustomerCompanies.InsertOnSubmit(company);
                        db.SubmitChanges();
                    }
```

Comment: double check the connection string you're using, maybe you're writing to the wrong db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [`SubmitChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges.aspx) is asynchronous, then the `db` object could be disposed before it has chance to finish, however, I don't see any evidence that it is asynchronous. Perhaps wrapping the [`SubmitChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges.aspx) call in a `try/catch` block will indicate any exceptions that have occurred. You could also look at the [`DataContext.ChangeConflicts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.changeconflicts.aspx) to see if any conflicts occurred.

Comment: any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I don't believe the call is asynchronous, but if it were, you would need to postpone the call to Dispose() until you were sure that the commit had finished.

Comment: You can test this easily by not wrapping the object with the using keyword, although this is not a fix - more just a way of determining where the problem lies.

Comment: Actually it was a missing primary key in my imported table. But no way you guys could know that :)

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the db.SubmitChanges() with a try catch and see if anything is thrown. It could also be a concurrency issue.